composer update error - Conclusion: don't install monolog/monolog 3.7.0 (conflict analysis result)
We are using Laravel Shift to upgrade from laravel 9 to 10 https://laravelshift.com/.
Shift created a PR modifying our composer.json.
It instructs us to run composer update to get the latest dependencies and update our lock file.
When we run composer update it gives this error message:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires phpnexus/cwh ^2.0.4 -> satisfiable by phpnexus/cwh[v2.0.4].
    - laravel/framework[v10.48.0, ..., v10.48.17] require monolog/monolog ^3.0 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[3.0.0, ..., 3.7.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install monolog/monolog 3.7.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.48 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.48.0, ..., v10.48.17].

We are using a Cloudwatch Logger using Monolog.
Not sure how to resolve this conflict.

You are probably specifying an older version of phpnexus/cwh, which is currently 3.1.1, not 2.0.4. Remove or change the version constraint for that package.

phpnexus/cwh in v2 requires Monolog v2, Laravel v10 requires Monolog v3. You need to update phpnexus/cwh at the same time.
Sadly, you can't decouple the updates, as Laravel v9 is not compatible with Monolog v3, but phpnexus/cwh already requires v3.
